# Update MySQL column when new date is greater than the existing one

Tags: mysql, upsert

I'm trying to update a column from a MySQL table so that it changes to current timestamp when the new date from another column is greater than the existing date from that column, and stays the same otherwise.

For example, let's say that I have a table with two columns, **enddate** and **enddate_modif**. If the date in **enddate** in the updating record is greater than the date in **enddate** in the existing table, I want **enddate_modif** to change to current timestamp. Otherwise, it keeps the same value.

How can I do it in MySQL?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use an after update trigger
something like this

```sql
if(New.enddate >Old.enddate ) then 
  update yourtable set enddate_modif=NOW() where Your_table_ID=NEW.Your_table_ID;
end iff;
```

Answer (score 0):

An after update trigger should do the trick.

Try:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `enddate_modif_trigger` BEFORE UPDATE ON `my_table`
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.enddate_modif = (SELECT CASE WHEN NEW.enddate  > enddate_modif
                                  THEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  
                                  ELSE NEW.enddate_modif
                                  END
                         FROM my_table 
                         );
```